# Filtrar tabla html de un proyecto APP SCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

Tengo un proyecto en APP SCRIPT para mostrar en una tabla html el contenido de una hoja de cálculo de GOOGLE SHEETS. La tabla HTML incluye un input para filtrar, pero solamente toma en cuenta los datos de la columna 2, quiero que el criterio ingresado busque en todas las columnas, intenté modificando esta parte del código .cells[1] de la siguiente forma .cells[1,2,3,4 ...] pero no funciona

¿Qué ajustes tengo que realizar para lograr eso?

Gracias !

```
function onInputChange(){
let inputText = document.getElementById("input-search").value.toString().toLowerCase();

let tableBody = document.getElementById("cursos");
let tableRows = tableBody.getElementsByTagName("tr");


for(let i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++){


let textoConsulta = tableRows[i].cells[1].textContent.toString().toLowerCase();
if( textoConsulta.indexOf(inputText) === -1 ) {
tableRows[i].style.visibility = "collapse";
} else {
tableRows[i].style.visibility = "";
}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo tenía prácticamente el mismo código de un tutorial que estaba siguiendo y lo solucioné simplemente quitando la parte de cells[1] de la variable textoXonsulta, me quedó así:

```
let textoConsulta = tableRows[i].textContent.toString().toUpperCase();
```

El código de la función completa me quedó como sigue:

```
  function onInputChange(){

let inputText = document.getElementById('buscarRegistro').value.toString().toUpperCase();
// console.log(inputText);

let tableBody = document.getElementById('tableBody-usuarios');
let tableRows = tableBody.getElementsByTagName("tr");
// console.log(tableRows); 
for(let i=0; i<tableRows.length; i++){
  let textoConsulta = tableRows[i].textContent.toString().toUpperCase();
  // console.log(textoConsulta);

  if(textoConsulta.indexOf(inputText) === -1){
    tableRows[i].style.visibility = "collapse";
  } else {
    tableRows[i].style.visibility = "";
  }

}
```

}

¡Espero que te también te funcione!